# Forming Palindrome from a String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, palindrome

I was solving Longest Palindrome in a String problem, where we are searching for the longest substring forming a palindrome. My code for the above is :

```
private static int palindrome(char[] ch, int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (i == j)
        return 1;

    // Base Case 2: If there are only 2 characters and both are same
    if (ch[i] == ch[j] && i + 1 == j)
        return 2;

    // If the first and last characters match
    if (ch[i] == ch[j])
        return palindrome(ch, i + 1, j - 1) + 2;

    // If the first and last characters do not match
    return max(palindrome(ch, i, j - 1), palindrome(ch, i + 1, j));

}
```

Now, I am curious to know that if instead of finding the longest substring, we make a palindrome choosing random characters (just one instance of each) from the string but in the same sequence as in String. Is it possible to do this in polynomial time?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. For string 'abcde'   would you be generating the palindrome 'c' or 'abcdedcba' ?

Comment: @RavindraHV see the last part of the question. I edited it.

Comment: I assume you want the longest possible palindrome?

Comment: @maraca yeah it will return 3.

Comment: @BenjyKessler yes if more than one exist then the longest one, just that we can select any character from the string, it need not be a substring, just that the characters of the palindrome formed come in the same sequence as that in the string.

Comment: In other words: your code isn't looking for the longest substring forming a palindrome, it is looking for the longest palindrome formed by taking the characters from the String in order and skipping is allowed. This is a difference. It is not a substring, can be, but doesn't have to.

Comment: Yes I realized that as well :)

Comment: @maraca the correct term is subsequence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence

Comment: @Shashank Thanks. I think it's just really confusing in the first sentence. Changing it to subsequence would solve everything.

Comment: I think this can be solved by applying a Longest Common Subsequence algorithm on the string and its reverse.

Comment: @jadhachem That is absolutely correct. And it's O(n^2) time. Mind posting an answer?

Comment: @Hack109 If I understand the question, you are trying to solve the problem of finding the longest substring forming a palindrome by building it - given the input string - rather than compare each of the letters against each other as the above implementation is attempting to do. Is this correct? If yes I do believe the approach is not significantly different from comparing the strings (even for building it you have to look at the other end) and therefore the algorithm (what you would have to build) should ideally run in polynomial time.

Comment: @jadhachem From the wiki [description](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subsequence&oldid=648797508), how would you decide what the two substrings are ?

Comment: @jadhachem I think you are correct in your approach, are you trying to find the LCS of the string and the reverse(string)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved by applying the [Longest Common Subsequence algorithm (LCS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).
LCS basically solves the following problem:

> Given two strings `a` and `b`, what is the longest string `c` that is a subsequence of both `a` and `b`?

A subsequence of a string is a sequence of characters from that string, in order, where skipping is allowed.

Now let us look at your problem.
We want to find the longest subsequence of a string `x` that is a palindrome.
But, by definition, a palindrome is a string that is read the same forward and backward.
Thus, the same palindrome will also be a subsequence of the *mirror image* of `x`.

Let us illustrate with the string `abca`.
Clearly, its two longest palindromic subsequences are `aba` and `aca`.
The mirror image of `abca` is `acba`.
What are its longest palindromic subsequences? Also `aba` and `aca`!

So we can now use LCS to solve your problem as follows:

```
String longestPalindromicSubsequence(String x) {
    // Get the mirror image of x
    String y = mirror(x);
    return LCS(x,y);
}
```

LCS can be done in `O(n^2)` time, where `n` is the length of the string.
Reversing a string takes linear time, so the final running time is `O(n^2)`.